# Setting a non-Algolia url parameter using the algolia helper

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm using Algolia's Instantsearch.js and I'd like to update a non-algolia-related uri query parameter from within my script. I see that I can set a query and search using the helper:

```
search.helper.setQuery('myquery').search();
```

This works, but I wonder if I can use the helper to set an additional uri parameter in the query string which isn't related to the Algolia query, but to the functionality of my site.

I see that there are a variety of functions to set query parameters in the documentation:
https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#url-helpers
but none of them seem to match what I'm looking for. Do you have suggestions on how I might update the querystring e.g: "country_code" to a value e.g: "FR" before executing the search.helper.setQuery above? I'd ideally like it so that both values are set in the uri at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instantsearch.js doesn't provide an API to do that, but it will keep every parameters that are set by other pieces of code. So in your case, if the URL already has the country_code, then you're done.

Otherwise if you want to do it from the front-end, then you can use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History) of the browser. In addition, you can use [getStateAsQueryString](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/docs/AlgoliaSearchHelper.html#getStateAsQueryString) on the helper which will serialize the current state and let you add more parameters (such as the country_code). But you need to be careful in using the same parameters used for initializing the URL mechanism in instantsearch (such as which attributes are used for the URL). If you use the defaults, you should be good.

For replacing the current URL / history state, the code would look like :

```
window.history.replaceState(
  null,
  'Title',
  '?' + helper.getStateAsQueryString({
    moreAttributes: {
      country_code: 'fr'
    }
  }));
```

For change the current value of your parameter then it will be like :

```
window.history.pushState(
  null,
  'Title',
  '?' + helper.getStateAsQueryString({
    moreAttributes: {
      country_code: 'de'
    }
  }));
```

Comment: Starting with a url like
`http://example.com/spaces/find2/?q=`
When using either `pushstate` or `replaceState` before and in conjunction with `search.helper.setQuery('Paris').search();` I end up with a url like this: with two values for q:
`http://example.com/spaces/find2/q=&cc=FR?q=Paris`
Further, with no '?' before the first q, it's not constructing a valid uri.

(continued..)

Comment: My current site actually starts with:
`http://example.com/spaces/find2?q=`

but this gets chopped down into this (dropping the find2 path)!
`http://example.com/spaces/q=&cc=FR?q=Paris`

So perhaps I will need to find a javascript url library to clean this up rather than using the built-in pushState / replaceState methods.

Comment: If you want to reuse the `q` parameter and you don't use a search box and you want the query parameter of your search to have the same value, then your initial solution. Do you have a URL to share so we can have a look?

Comment: Thanks @bobylito - I emailed you. Also noted that ```console.log(search.helper.getStateAsQueryString({
     moreAttributes: {
        country_code: 'FR'
      }
       }
)```
only outputs e.g: ```"q=&cc=FR"```, not the section of the query after the '?'. Thank you!!

Comment: Ok, so the problem was solved by Tim Carry - with a small tweak: to make it work, it's necessary to add '?' + helper.getStateAsQueryString({ .... and then replacement works for both pushState and replaceState, so that should probably be added to the solution. Bravo!